# RxJS BehaviourSubject subscription is called once in onInit

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm new in RxJS but I want to learn. currently I face to some problems: I have a parent component(renders popup and table component)

```
  providers: [
    DataService
  ]
class AppComponent {
  constructor(private readonly dialogService: DialogService) {
    //init something
  }
  
  openNewTestDataDialog(): void {
    let ref = this.dialogService.open(TestComponent, {
      header: 'New Test',
      closable: true,
      closeOnEscape: true,
      autoZIndex: true,
      data: {
        data: undefined
      }
    });
  }
}
```

here I have DinamicDialog TestComponent - its modal where I can add item and save it

```
 class CompanyDetailsComponent { 
   constructor(private readonly dataService: DataService) {
   //
  }
 
  updateItem(updatedItem?: Item) {
      if (updatedItem.id) {
        this.dataService.updateItem(updatedItem).subscribe(
          data => this.dataService.getItems(),//here I'm trying to emit getting new data
          error => this.handleError(error)
        );
      } 
  }
  }
```

Also I have another component which has subscription

```
 class TableComponent {
    subscription: Subscription | undefined;
    items: Item[] = [];
    
  constructor(private readonly dataService: DataService) {
    //
  }
  
    ngOnInit() {

    this.subscription = this.dataService.getItemSubject().subscribe(x => {
      if(x) {
        this.items = x;
      }
    });
    this.dataService.getItems();
  }
}
```

And the service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'})
export class DataService {

  itemSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Item[]>([]);

  constructor(private readonly httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

  getItemSubject(): Observable<any> {
    return this.itemSubject.asObservable();
  }

  getItems() {
    const url = decorateUrl(UrlConstants.ULR_ITEM);
    this.httpClient.get<Company[]>(url)
      .subscribe(items => this.itemSubject.next([...items]));
  }
  }
```

The problem: subscription in TableComponent is called only once when this component is rendered and when I try to add new item in popup observers array for BehaviorSubject is empty. What I'm doing wrong? thanks!

Comment: Services provided at component level are created along for each instance of the component. At the result your service provided in root is a different service than the service provided for AppComponent. I guess you can simpy remove the provided statement at AppComponent

Answer (score 1):

The common usage of services should let an instance exist independently of your component.

Maybe remove it from your component providers, and place it into your module providers could help

Comment: yes, exactly! will remember forever) thanks a lot!